# AppleScript pass shell output list to "choose from list"?

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator

I'm writing a simple AppleScript to use in an Automator app that asks a user to select from a list of available Backblaze B2 buckets, with the goal of passing that selection into the shell script that rclone mounts the remote bucket as a drive.

This is my script to get the list of available buckets:

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
set bucketGet to every text item of (do shell script "/usr/local/bin/rclone lsf backblaze: --dirs-only")
set bucketChoice to (choose from list bucketList)
```

The `rclone lsf` output looks like:

```
bucket-1/
bucket-2/
bucket-3/
bucket-4/
```

But this only puts the first line `bucket-1/` into the pop-up box to choose from. How do I get all lines of the output to be in the list to choose from?

EDIT: I tried replacing `set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","` with `set AppleScript's text item delimiters to character id 10`, but that gave me the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this myself:

```
set bucketGet to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/rclone lsf backblaze: --dirs-only"
set bucketList to paragraphs of bucketGet
set bucketChoice to choose from list bucketList with prompt "Please select a bucket to mount:"
```

Now I get all the results as options to choose from.